# Gnome-terminal- how do i open a new winodow asking to authentificate as root?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have a script that checks for usb devices. If the device is valid, (it's in my database, a text file) my script mounts it, and if the device is not in my database, i get a messgae "invalid device detected", and the device doesn't mount. When an invalid device is detected, i want to open a terminal, showing "invalid device "usb_name" detected. Please intoduce your root password to mount it." . And if the  password is correct, and want the _invalid_usb_name to be written in my database , and so, it will be a valid device now. How exactly do i open that terminal in my script asking for my root password ? It's a bash script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gnome-terminal -e "sudo bash"` will open a new terminal window asking for root password.

Comment: Thank you. I used xterm - e "su root". But how can i make it to run a new script in it? i tryed xterm -e "su root ; second_script.sh" but it doesn's work.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't know :( I've searched for a while, but all my attempts to execute more commands failed. All i know is that you need to pass these commands to the shell that's running there, not to the terminal application itself.